# unix text file find double entries

Tags: shell

I've the following file which has entries like this:

```
cn: 5f78ee78-54a6-41b7-bff5-a34ff4f7fc4d  
7379800474  
cn: f6c16630-a194-4e64-8bb9-5edab380340a  
2193668474  
cn: 2ed03469-eaf2-4f0a-b5b2-4e0b3fab402c  
5051108453  
cn: d28fc57c-0ff8-4b08-9120-6614e35da185  
9518351168  
cn: 3762c0ec-2a6e-4bf9-afe5-bf144e1f658d  
4902143367  
cn: 600bdcfe-bf0a-4735-95bc-fbe1f2d521d5  
3239279952  
cn: 8d7d1204-4d5b-48ab-8f2c-3ab5d7da2d3d  
3339625694  
3546846448  
3339625694  
3546846448  
cn: e52f7b5a-9061-4168-9622-f4f0c3cd863c  
4853840278  
cn: e617bf31-58a9-412f-9cac-77620f203c1b  
8075983683  
cn: c42d6609-544b-412e-abd5-c76eb1fa7ec1  
3938895718  
cn: 33359ce9-e57e-494a-a08b-c07a647733f4  
1623732669  
8713087228  
1623732669
```

I need to know which `cn` has double entries

A `cn` could have more than one entry.

So the `cn` `8d7d1204-4d5b-48ab-8f2c-3ab5d7da2d3d` has two double entries in the example above:

```
3339625694  
3546846448  
3339625694  
3546846448
```

Comment: please check [ask]. You should show your efforts, as well as a clear [mcve] on what is the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

`sort filename | uniq -d` will list any line that appears more than once.

EDIT

The requirements have changed, and you will most likely need a `perl` script.

Read the input line by line, look for each line that begins with `cn`.  After that, each time you see a line that doesn't start with `cn`, you increment a counter for that particular item by 1.  The next time you see a line that starts with `cn`, check your counters and see if any of them are greater than 1.  Then clear your counters and start again.

Comment: that does not work, because I don't which cn have the double entry's

Comment: do you've an perl example ?